# Accessing managedClasspath of sbt subprojects

Tags: sbt

I'm converting an sbt 0.7.x build script to sbt 0.11.2. I'm writing a task to collect various JARs together from subprojects. In the old build, part of the task does the following:

```
deployedProjects.foreach {
  p: BasicScalaProject =>
    p.managedClasspath(config("compile")) --- p.managedClasspath(config("provided"))
    // etc
}
```

How can I do the equivalent in sbt 0.11?

**Updated to add:**

In particular:

- How can I write a task that depends on a list of settings/tasks? For example, how would I write a task that depends on all the managedClasspaths from a List of subprojects (without bundling it all into a tuple).
- Is there a particular scope for getting the managed jars that are or are not marked as "provided"?

Answer (score 0):

In sbt 0.11.x there is the task managedClasspath:

```
> inspect managed-classpath
[info] Task: scala.collection.Seq[sbt.Attributed[java.io.File]]
[info] Description:
[info]  The classpath consisting of external, managed library dependencies.
[info] Provided by:
[info]  {file:/Users/heiko/tmp/test/}default-f3fb6c/compile:managed-classpath
[info] Dependencies:
[info]  compile:classpath-configuration
[info]  compile:classpath-types
[info]  compile:update
[info] Reverse dependencies:
[info]  compile:external-dependency-classpath
[info] Delegates:
[info]  compile:managed-classpath
[info]  *:managed-classpath
[info]  {.}/compile:managed-classpath
[info]  {.}/*:managed-classpath
[info]  */compile:managed-classpath
[info]  */*:managed-classpath
[info] Related:
[info]  test:managed-classpath
[info]  runtime:managed-classpath
```

Looking at the delegates you see that you can scope this task to various configurations, e.g. *compile*:

```
> show compile:managed-classpath
[info] Updating {file:/Users/heiko/tmp/test/}default-f3fb6c...
[info] Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.9.1 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] ArraySeq(Attributed(/Users/heiko/.sbt/boot/scala-2.9.1/lib/scala-library.jar))
```

Comment: thanks, but I'm still not sure exactly how to achieve what I was after -- I've updated the question to be more precise.